# openlayer intellisense not working in visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, openlayers-3

i have a problem with openlayer 3 which is intelisense is not working in visual studio 2017 v15.7.2 (updated to latest) i have done these things and they didi not work:
1-tools -> options->text editor -> all languages -> check the auto list member 
2-tools -> options->text editor ->java script -> check the auto list member 
3-i even installed web storm but even in there it's not working either
though jquery intelisense works like a charm in both IDE ..
any ideas?